# Is static private IP excluded from AWS VPC DHCP pool?

Tags: aws-vpc

I have legacy app that has to have 3 static private ip addresses.

I use 192.168.10.0/24 for private subnet and 192.168.10.100 , 192.168.10.101 , 192.168.10.102 as IPs that are manually assigned to EC2 with that app.

My question is: are those IPs excluded from AWS VPC DHCP pool?

If new instances launched in the same subnet could they get those IPs from DHCP and be in a conflict with existing instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "no". I have this issue too (Google brings me here).
While the IPs that are attributed by the DHCP service are not reusable, if you have manually assigned a secondary IP to an instance, this IP is not excluded from the DHCP pool.
However, you can reassign the secondary IP to another instance.